# Search to find two numbers that cover 95% of the area under a curve

Tags: r, function, statistics, bayesian, confidence-interval

**Background:**

I have two columns of numbers (column "**dd**", and column "**yy**", **see below to access this data**). When I plot **"dd"** (**X-axis**) against "**yy**" (**Y-axis**), using:

`plot(dd, yy, ty="l", xlab = "dd", ylab ="yy", lwd=2, xaxs="i")`

I get this:

[image]

**Coding question:**

Moving from **"-Inf"** to **"0"** u**p until what other point covers 95% of the area under this curve?** **In other words,** we want to see the **two numbers that correspond to the two ARROW HEADS TIPS** if the arrow is to cover 95% of the area under this curve?

Here is the **R code to easily import this small data** into your Rstudio:

```
id <- "0B5V8AyEFBTmXM1VIYUYxSG5tSjQ"

Data <- read.csv(paste0("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=",id,"&export=download"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "covers"? Do you mean the area below both the curve and the blue line segment should equal the total area below the curve?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta, think of the total area of this curve as 100% or 1. If the start point for the curve is "0", how much to the left we should move to get to 95% of the area under the curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: My previous approximation was not very accurate. It turns out the `pracma` package has a function, `cumtrapz`, which approximates integrals with trapezoids and outputs the sum at each point starting from the left. Using that function gives a more accurate answer.

```
library(pracma)
points <- read.csv(paste0("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=",id,"&export=download")) 
area   <- cumtrapz(points$dd, points$yy)
ind    <- rev(which(area[length(area)] - area > .95))[1]

point  <- points$dd[ind]
point

# [1] -0.06406406
```

Comment: Not unless you know the area under the curve from `-inf` to `-0.2`, because your data only goes to `-0.2`.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but obviously there's no way to get a dataset with infinitely many rows. You'd have to just get data that goes to a point when `yy` is small enough to assume the area to the left is negligible. Either that or fit a function to your current data and integrate that function.

Comment: @parvinkarimi Oops, I meant to reference `points.rev` in `delta.dd`, `area`, etcetera. Fixed

Comment: It is 95% from 0 to the left

Comment: If you want 95% from -0.2 to the right just assign `ind <- which(area > .95)[1]` instead of the above definition of `ind`

Comment: Something is still very wrong Ahhhh! I'm using `area <- cumtrapz(points$dd, points$yy) ;
ind1 <- which(area > .025)[1];  point1 <- points$dd[ind1]` and this must be in the vicinity of `- .074`? I'm sure I got it yesterday but not today !! Ahhhh! Can you import the data and run this, please?

Comment: The data is different than it was yesterday.